# How to know which is my current environment at Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am following a phoenix book which says:

> Be careful. The ecto.migrate task will migrate the database for your
>   current environment. So far, we’ve been running the dev environment.
>   To change the environment, you’d set the MIX_ENV operating-system
>   environment variable.

But I dont know which is mi current environment, I print echo MIX_ENV variable and it's empty, how can I knowwhich environment I am in and/or change from environments?

Comment: The `MIX_ENV` environment variable will default to `:dev`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `MIX_ENV` environment variable is empty `Mix.env` defaults to `:dev`:

```
$ iex -S mix
> Mix.env
# => :dev
```

If you set `MIX_ENV` to another existing environment (test or prod, then `Mix.env` will return it:

```
$ MIX_ENV=test iex -S mix
> Mix.env
# => :test
```

There's no need to define another config.

To get something from your config use for example `Application.get_env/2`:

```
Application.get_env(:your_app_name, YourAppName)[:adapter]
# => Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

I define a sitetype in config/(dev|prod).exs like following, and get the site type with `Application.get_env(:app_name, :site_type)`. In this way, you can get the type even if prod env distributed with distillery for example.

`config :app_name, :site_type, :dev`
or
`config :app_name, :site_type, :prod`